# Entity Framework 6 CF: Remove One-to-Many

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

My classes are something like:

```
public class Contact
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }
    public int? ContactId { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to remove a `Contact` that has in it's collection a `Person`, I get this error:

> The primary key value cannot be deleted because references to this key
>   still exist. [ Foreign key constraint name =
>   FK_dbo.Persons_dbo.Contacts_ContactsId ]

I set the `ContactId` to `int?` so it could be nullable, and the database says it's a nullable FK, and it works fine in general. Just when I try to delete the entity with the collection that I get this error.

I want to be able to **delete a Contact, but not the Persons inside it**, what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behaviour of EF is to null foreign keys when their principal relationship is deleted. However, no database rule will be setup. In order for EF to issue update statements on the foreign keys of the dependents, they will need to be loaded into the context.
So make sure when you delete `Contact` all it's dependent `Person` entities have been loaded.

Comment: This works! Thanks! But, I think it's horrible from a performance point of view... Instead of deleting one record, I will have to load a 1000 and then make the updates, if my connection with the DB is over the Internet and I am running the code in an app, this can be a huge performance bottleneck

Comment: Yeah I know what you mean, it's a bit rubbish. You could possibly manually setup the database rule with SQl or possibly use some of the EF extension libraries? Maybe they can provide a more efficient way.

Comment: I found only complicated options unfortunately, I will try to look more.